# Trouble with running an application with python and watson

Tags: python, watson

I'm using the watson speech to text api with python 3 for a project, and I have to write a new command that will open a project but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.
Here is the code I have for the command,

```
# Adding a command to launch an application
if x[0] ['alternatives'] [0] ['transcript'] == 'run ' and Command_State is 'Started':
        print("Running...")
        Command_State = 'Run'
        self.listening = True
```

The program will see the command and set the Command_State to 'Run' I then have an if statement that I plan on putting the code to run the application.

```
# If statement to, watch for Command_State to switch to 'Run".
if Command_State == 'Run':
        print("Running chrome")
        # Code goes here
        pass
```

Currently, I just have a print statement and a pass in the if statement but here is where I want to put the code to run an application. I was thinking about maybe running it through cmd but the only code that I found that talks about that is outdated and doesn't work. Anyways, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this here's the code I used. I decided to just do it all in one if statement because it is much easier that way, but if you wanted you could have a set command to change the Command_State to run then listen for other commands such as "Netflix" to open netflix or "I hate myself" to open Internet Explorer.

```
# Adding a command to launch an application
if x[0] ['alternatives'] [0] ['transcript'] == 'run ' and Command_State is 'Started':
    print("Running...")
    Command_State = None
    self.listening = True
    subprocess.Popen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
```

You can replace the path I have with anything you want as long as it is an executable. Well I mean I guess you could try but no promises that it would work.